# Javascript popup confirmation for two submit buttons

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am new to php, mysql, and javascript. Recently I have been working on creating a popups for each button. When I put the code in the form tag, the code works, however it is a general popup for both add and delete. I would like a confirm popup for adding and deleting. I tried putting the code on the input tags but the code did not run. What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<form action="da.php" method="post">
name:<input type="text" name="input1">
<br/>
<input onSubmit="if(!confirm('Submit?')){return false;}" name="add1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input onSubmit="if(!confirm('Delete?')){return false;}" name="del1" type="submit" value="Delete" /> 

</form>
</body>
```

PHP

```
define('db_name', 'demo');
define('db_user', 'root');
define('db_password', 'pw');
define('db_host', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect (db_host, db_user, db_password);

if (!$link) {
die('could not connect: '. mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(db_name, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('can\'t use' . db_name . ': ' . mysql_error());
}


$value = $_POST['input1'];



if (isset($_POST['add1'])) {
$sql = "insert into demo (name) values ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

}

elseif (isset($_POST['del1'])) {
$sql = "delete from demo where name = ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

}



mysql_close();

header( 'Location:  localhost://da-form.html') ;

?>
```

Comment: try `onclick` instead of `onSubmit`

Comment: @hamed ali khan Your suggestion worked! Thanks a bunch, if you post that as an answer, I'll pick it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `onclick` instead of `onSubmit`

`onSubmit` is usually used on the form tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.confirm in javascript to get confirmation from user.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="da.php" method="post">
name:<input type="text" name="input1">
<br/>
<input onClick="return confirm('Submit?');" name="add1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input onClick="return confirm('Delete?');" name="del1" type="submit" value="Delete" /> 

</form>
```